# Getting allow users from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-authorization

I tried to getting an allowed users from web.config to access the application and deny others and redirect them to another page. Here my code:

**Config**

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <allow users="anwar,abdulaziz"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

**Code**

```
AuthorizationSection configSection = (AuthorizationSection)
    ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/authorization");
var users = new List<string>();
var rules = configSection.Rules;
foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
{
    if (rule.Action != AuthorizationRuleAction.Allow)
    {
        foreach (string user in rule.Users)
        {
            Response.Redirect("UnauthorizedUsers.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it working? Is it not working? Any error? What's the question?

Comment: it is always redirect to UnauthorizedUsers.aspx if the user is allowed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to redirect unauthorized users to another page.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Status.StartsWith("401"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Redirect("UnauthorizedUsers.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get an infinite redirect loop, that's an indication that your UnauthorizedUsers.aspx is inaccessible to unauthorized users. You'll have to exclude it from your general authorization rules, either by putting the other files in a subfolder and securing that (instead of your entire project), or by adding a separate authorization rule in.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please upvote my answer (if you have the rep) and accept it by pressing the mark below the score.

Comment: it is kind of help thanx